# Watcher 'asleep' when data takes a while to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive which auto expands the textarea on the return key. It does that however when I pre-populate the textarea I want it to grow to the size of the content.

My watcher kind of falls asleep when data takes a bit to load. I have to click on the textarea to interact with it for it to initially auto expand.

Ideally I want to stop the watcher but not the on input listener once the initial auto expand is complete.

Here's my code

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.tab = 1;
  
  //fake async call
  $timeout(function() {
    vm.text = 'fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r ';
  }, 1500);
})

.directive('autoResize', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function autoResizeLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
          console.log('listen');
          if((ngModel.$viewValue || ngModel.$modelValue) && element[0].scrollHeight > 0) {
              console.log('view value appeared', ngModel.$viewValue);
              console.log('element[0].scrollHeight',element[0].scrollHeight);

              element.css({ 'height': 'auto', 'overflow-y': 'hidden' });
              element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');

              console.log('stop listening here');
          }
      });

      element.on('input', function () {
          element.css({ 'height': 'auto', 'overflow-y': 'hidden' });
          element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');

      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
 
      <a ng-click="vm.tab = 1">Tab 1</a>
      <a ng-click="vm.tab = 2">Tab 2</a>
      
      <div ng-show="vm.tab === 2">
         <textarea auto-resize ng-model="vm.text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle/JSBin/CodePen reproducing your issue ? I don't really manage to reproduce it on my side

Comment: I've added a snippet. I think there's something wrong with this and ng-show as I have the field under a tab which isn't opened.

Comment: Watchers only evaluate their watch expression when there are user events or framework events such data arriving from the server. What you call "asleep" is normal behavior for the AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 0):

Watchers only evaluate their watch expression when there are user events or framework events such data arriving from the server. What you call "asleep" is normal behavior for the AngularJS framework.

Instead of using a watcher, use the [$formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) and [$viewChangeListeners](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) pipelines:

```
app.directive('autoResize', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function autoResizeLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          $timeout(resize);
          return data;
      });

      ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
          $timeout(resize);
      });

      function resize() {
          console.log("resize");
          element.css({ 'height': 'auto', 'overflow-y': 'hidden' });
          element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The ngModelController invokes the [$formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) functions when it gets new model values from the framework. It invokes the [$viewChangeListeners](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) when it gets new values from the user.

### THE DEMO

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.tab = 1;
  
  //fake async call
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log("data");
    vm.text = 'fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r fsafsafsafasfsa \r ';
  }, 1500);
})

.directive('autoResize', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function autoResizeLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          $timeout(resize);
          return data;
      });

      ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
          $timeout(resize);
      });

      function resize() {
          console.log("resize");
          element.css({ 'height': 'auto', 'overflow-y': 'hidden' });
          element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
 
      <a ng-click="vm.tab = 1">Tab 1</a>
      <a ng-click="vm.tab = 2">Tab 2</a>
      
      <div ng-if="vm.tab === 2">
         <textarea auto-resize ng-model="vm.text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good to know that, however this only works when ng-if is used but not ng-show.